# How can I bind the results of Web service to a ListView?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, web-applications

I'm new to ASP.NET so I apologize if this is a basic question.

I have a Web application. This web application has a ListView on it.
From this web app I make calls to a web service which returns data from a  database. I return the data from the web service using the following format:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Record> Search()
{
    List<Record> list = new List<Record>();
    /* Populate list with data from a db */
    return list;
}

public class Record
{
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public int ageInYears;
}
```

Now I would like from the Web Application to show the data on a listview. Is there a way of doing this by using the Data Source property of the Listview or the only way is to populate the listview manually?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is the webservice in the same project?

Comment: No, they are in different projects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. use datasource, then try calling databind().

Comment: But how do I assign it to the listview?